# Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, execjs

I have other rails app on this server working fine...
I have `nodejs` install on my serveur
I have `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` in gemfile,
I try `bundle install`,
I try `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)` in prod conf

but nothing resolve the bug...

```
 [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (www-data) and Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Warning: compilation didn't succeed. To learn why, read this file:
     /var/www/ddemarque/passenger_native_support-hxohsj.log
 [passenger_native_support.so] finding downloads for the current Ruby interpreter...
     (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Could not download https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases/download/release-6.0.8/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
     Trying next mirror...
     Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.8/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
     Trying next mirror...
     Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/6.0.8/rubyext-ruby-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: no download tool found (curl or wget required)
 [passenger_native_support.so] will not be used (can't compile or download) 
  --> Passenger will still operate normally.
Error: The application encountered the following error: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.15/lib/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    /var/www/ddemarque/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/www/ddemarque/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    /var/www/ddemarque/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `instance_eval'
    /home/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `initialize'
    config.ru:1:in `new'
    config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:390:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I force gem execjs to down to 2.7.0 since 2.8.1, it's works...

Comment: I have the same problem with execjs (= 2.7)

Comment: what version of ruby do you have? I use 2.5.1 and rails 6 on my case ;)